# Azure custom deployment script - remove additional files at desitination

Tags: azure, kudu

When using a [custom deployment script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) for a Github to Azure continuous deployments how do you get the script to remove additional files at destination the same way in which you can when publishing through Visual Studio (VS screenshot below).

[image]

If it helps, more specifically my script is based off this tutorial - https://github.com/aranasoft/todo-azurewebsites/wiki/Deploying-to-Azure.

I'm hoping that it can be done, and only with a few lines of code that can be added to the script to intelligently delete only the additional files, or maybe a configuration option for the KuduSync cmd.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `rmdir` command to your deployment script? It seems to me that you've answered your own question. :)

Comment: I haven't tried that. To clarify - Ideally I don't want to drop the whole folder as I expect that will cause deployment to take a lot longer, and take the site down. I think the VS option intelligently deletes only the additional files. I'll edit the question to remove confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will probably work.

Put this in file `f`:

```
diff -ReferenceObject  (gci -Recurse $Env:DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE | % { $_.FullName.TrimStart($Env:DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE) }) `
     -DifferenceObject (gci -Recurse $Env:DEPLOYMENT_TARGET | % { $_.FullName.TrimStart($Env:DEPLOYMENT_TARGET) }) |
  ? SideIndicator -eq "=>" |
  % { Join-Path -Path $Env:DEPLOYMENT_TARGET $_.InputObject } |
  % { write "Removing $_"; rm $_ }
}
```

and call it from your Kudu deployment script, e.g. `powershell.exe -File f`

If you're more comfortable with `bash`, it's available as well on the Web App hosts and you can tell Kudu to execute bash scripts to by changing the `config`-section in `.deployment`, e.g. to something in the lines of `command = bash deployment.sh`.

Comment: Cheers. It looks like it should work, but I get a syntax error: `Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition`. All the `}` look right though. Do you have hints?

Comment: If it's related to this block, I'd would guess you're missing the last curly bracket. If not, I'd suggest using the PowerShell ISE or another editor with syntax highlighting.

Comment: There are no errors in the PowerShell ISE. But still the syntax error in the deploy.cmd. Calling powershell from within a cmd is fine right?

Comment: Yep. But I forgot that batch files are executed line by line. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! All this effort just to run gulp on Azure. I'm now hitting the horrible 'The specified path, file name, or both are too long' error on the `remove-item` command. I guess that's a different hurdle though. Thank again.